# Identify when Unity Button Enters Pressed State

Tags: unity, 2d, sprites, unity-ui

I am trying to create a UI Button Prefab with a text child element that I would like to use all over my application. Its intended behavior is very simple:

- Its size would be dependent on the text's width (this has been achieved using content size fitter and a horizontal layout group).
- Its states would be done using sprite swap (this had also been done partly)

[image]

The problem is that the pressed state uses an image on which the button is visually pressed (its top moves downward a few pixels). This is a nice effect and the image works great, however, I cannot make the text move in synchrony with the image to sell the downward movement.

My way of thinking was to use an initial padding of 4 at the bottom in the horizontal layout group (to move the text upward) then change it to 2 when the button enters a pressed state. Something like this:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ButtonController : MonoBehaviour {
    public Button buttonComponent;
    public HorizontalLayoutGroup buttonLayout;

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update() {
        RectOffset tempPadding = new RectOffset(
        buttonLayout.padding.left,
        buttonLayout.padding.right,
        buttonLayout.padding.top,
        buttonLayout.padding.bottom);
    
       if (buttonComponent.isPressed) { //This does not work OFC!
        tempPadding.bottom = 2;
       } else {
           tempPadding.bottom = 4;
       }     

       buttonLayout.padding = tempPadding;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I cannot seem to identify when the button enters said pressed state, which seem like a simple enough problem yet I cannot find an answer to it. I've looked all over the internet but couldn't find anything useful.

Comment: Is [SpriteState.pressedSprite](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.SpriteState.html) applicable here? (Accessed via [Selectable.spriteState](https://docs.unity3d.com/2018.3/Documentation/ScriptReference/UI.Selectable-spriteState.html))

Comment: You might be onto something, but by itself it doesn't do anything. I think it might just check if the sprite exists, and since it does, it always gives back true.

Comment: Are you able to compare that sprite to the one being displayed in the button's image component?

Comment: Hmm, good idea. I will check later tonight!

Comment: @DMGregory, I was able to try your idea out, but unfortunately it does not work. The problem is that the value of the button's image property never changes; it always gives back its default sprite for normal state regardless of state change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Guys over at the Unity3D sub-Reddit had come up with a good solution, using the even handler. I have not come up with this answer, and I don't want to take credit for it, but there is no one else to post it here; so, I have to:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

public class ButtonController : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
{
public HorizontalLayoutGroup buttonLayout;

public void OnPointerDown (PointerEventData pointerEventData)
{
    RectOffset tempPadding = new RectOffset(
        buttonLayout.padding.left,
        buttonLayout.padding.right,
        buttonLayout.padding.top,
        buttonLayout.padding.bottom);

    tempPadding.bottom = 0;
    buttonLayout.padding = tempPadding;
}

public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData pointerEventData)
{
    RectOffset tempPadding = new RectOffset(
     buttonLayout.padding.left,
     buttonLayout.padding.right,
     buttonLayout.padding.top,
     buttonLayout.padding.bottom);

    tempPadding.bottom = 4;
    buttonLayout.padding = tempPadding;
}
}
```